# Access to bash arrays in gnuplot

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, array, gnuplot

In a bash script I have several arrays which I need to access in a gnuplot code:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
# fill array a[*] and b[*]
...
gnuplot <<EOF
  do for [j=0:10] { # access ${a[j]} and ${b[j]} }
EOF
```

The problem is that `${a[j]}` in the gnuplot code is not interpreted as element j of the array `a`.

How can I solve that?

Comment: I assume your she-bang line is a copy/paste typo for '#!/bin/bash' ?

Comment: No, it was a real typo ;-) Anyway the code is just an example, and the problem remains...

Comment: Possibly related: [gnuplot shell variable substitution and arrays](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52453/gnuplot-shell-variable-substitution-and-arrays)